# JSTL Format Number in million

Tags: format, jstl

I have a number like, `48371000000` i need to display it like `48371`.

Using JSTL, I tried like

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="salesFormat" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" value="48371000000"/>
Output: $48,371,000,000.00
```

Do I need to use any pattern?

Please Help, Thank in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get an alternative like,

Firstly I am getting the value by dividing it by 1000000.

Thanks guys.